# bootstrap-switch: Disable/Enable other options on change

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-switch

I use bootstrap-switch and have different buttons. Given a change, I want to give other attributes as parameters like in this sample:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="values[{$optionName}]" value="1" data-to-enable="values[optionName1],values[optionName5],values[optionName50],values[optionName100],values[optionName333]" />
```

I want these options to be disabled on unchecked (or when it's unchecked on page load), and enabled (or when it's checked on page load) on checked.

Comment: Can you provide more HTML of what you want ? plus the javascript code you already tried ? And describe exactly what you want, it is hard to tell at this moment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the javascript code you want:

```
$(function() {

    var toggleSwitch = function(ev) {
        var _this = $(ev.currentTarget);
        var toChange = _this.data("to-enable").split(",");
        var state = _this.bootstrapSwitch("state");

        $("input.switch").each(function(el, index) {
            if($.inArray($(this).prop("name"), toChange) >= 0) {
                $(this).bootstrapSwitch("disabled", state);
            }
        });
    }       

    $("input").bootstrapSwitch();
    $("input[id^='switchHandler']").each(function(){
        $(this).bootstrapSwitch("state", $(this).data("checked"));
        $(this).on("switchChange.bootstrapSwitch", toggleSwitch);
        $(this).trigger("switchChange.bootstrapSwitch");
    });

});
```

And here is a working [**jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/xd4e1jjp/10/)

Comment: That is great. Thank you. I have change it with this: $("[id^=switchHandler]").on("switchChange.bootstrapSwitch", function(){ that I can make different switchHandler. Great. Givs a change to change it that the script disable/enable the buttons and not checked/unchecked?

Comment: Q: You are great. Thank you. Givs a change, to check id="switchHandler" on pageload if it checked or unchecked to enable/disable the switch from data-to-enable? At this moment, when I checked the switchHandler on page load, the option data-to-enable is the wrong way

Comment: @Koda Updated again. Now when the page load, the switch are based on the initial value of `$("#toggleSwitch")`. If you want to invert this behaviour, just negate the `state` variable` (by doing this: `!_this.bootstrapSwitch("state")`)

Comment: Thank you. Last one. Sorry. With your code I have two problems: 1. Givs a change that value="1" not say if checked or not? For me its better with checked="checked" or data-is-checked="0/1". 2. In commend before, I have write you that I have change it to $("[id^=switchHandler]") becauce I have more than one switchhandler. But with this it don't work in your new sample

Comment: @Koda There you are

Comment: One bug: When I change to checked="false" or delete it, the checkbox is allready checked

Comment: @Koda Fixed. I've used data-attribute instead of checked property because of the behaviour of bootstrap-switch.

Comment: Sorry again. Extremly rare I have a name like this: <input class="switch" type="checkbox" name="values[optionName56][]" value="1" />. Do you see a way that the can disabled too, or is this too much?